# Network Manager 0.8.999 and Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, network-manager

Is there a way to make Ubuntu One understand that I have a network connection after upgrading to network-manager-0.8.999?

FYI: Update manager also thinks that I have no internet-connection, but ignores the fact and continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=com.ubuntuone.SyncDaemon --type=method_call /events com.ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.Events.push_event "string:SYS_NET_CONNECTED" "dict:string:string:"
```

Comment: This did not work for me. :(
Anything else I can do?
I can't find an answer anywhere. :(